# Initiating OAuth2 Authorization Code flow with SPA Client and Web API with Spring Security

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I have a java web api which is configured with Spring Security with AWS Cognito OAuth2 provider. I have separate Web Application (ReactJs) which makes calls to the api, so the ui needs to login for the protected endpoints.

The web app which is hosted separately runs the below code when Login button is clicked:

`window.location.assign("http://<api-server:port>/oauth2/authorization/cognito)`

which initiates the flow by eventually redirecting to `https://<provider-url>/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&scope=openid&state=???&redirect_uri=http://<api-server:port>/login/oauth2/code/cognito&nonce=???`. This seems to work but, is this the right approach? Also how do I set state parameters (I need it to store the url of the web page which initiated the call so I can get the user back to the initiating page post login. This currently is hardcoded in SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess)

Another approach seems to be to call the authorize end point directly `https://<provider-url>/oauth2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=xxx&scope=openid&state=???&redirect_uri=http://<api-server:port>/login/oauth2/code/cognito&nonce=???`

In this case, is it safe to maintain client_id on the browser and if so, what should I provide for nonce and state. With the previous approach it automatically populates these values with state being some undecipherable value.

Answer (score 0):

Before sending the user browser to your authorization server, you have to ensure that he has a session on the Spring OAuth2 client with `oauth2Login` (create the values for the parameters you are wanting to set).

Also the configuration for the authorization server and the OAuth2 client registration are in the Spring application already.

To avoid configuration duplication (and discrepancies), as well as ensuring that the frontend has an opened session, I usually process as in [this tutorial I wrote](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials/bff): Spring OAuth2 client exposes the URI at which an authorization code flow can be initiated, and the frontend calls this endpoint to start login. Something like that:

```java
@RestController
@Observed(name = "GatewayController")
public class GatewayController {
    private final SpringAddonsOidcClientProperties addonsClientProperties;
    private final List<LoginOptionDto> loginOptions;

    public GatewayController(OAuth2ClientProperties clientProps, SpringAddonsOidcProperties addonsProperties) {
        this.addonsClientProperties = addonsProperties.getClient();
        this.loginOptions = clientProps
            .getRegistration()
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> "authorization_code".equals(e.getValue().getAuthorizationGrantType()))
            .map(e -> new LoginOptionDto(e.getValue().getProvider(), "%s/oauth2/authorization/%s".formatted(addonsClientProperties.getClientUri(), e.getKey())))
            .toList();
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/login-options", produces = "application/json")
    public Flux<LoginOptionDto> getLoginOptions(Authentication auth) throws URISyntaxException {
        final boolean isAuthenticated = auth instanceof OAuth2AuthenticationToken;
        return Flux.fromStream(isAuthenticated ? Stream.empty() : this.loginOptions.stream());
    }

    static record LoginOptionDto(@NotEmpty String label, @NotEmpty String loginUri) {}
}
```

I also change the response status of the first redirection in the authorization-code flow from `302` to something in the `2xx` range with a custom `(Server)RedirectStrategy` (the interface depends on the app being a servlet or a reactive app):

```java
http.oauth2Login(oauth2 -> {
    oauth2.authorizationRedirectStrategy(preAuthorizationCodeRedirectStrategy);
    ...
});
```

With something like that in servlets (give maybe `204 - No content` as constructor param and provide the frontend with the ability to force the status with a custom header on the request):

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SpringAddonsOauth2RedirectStrategy implements RedirectStrategy {
    public static final String RESPONSE_STATUS_HEADER = "X-RESPONSE-STATUS";

    private final HttpStatus defaultStatus;

    @Override
    public void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, String location) throws IOException {
        final var requestedStatus = request.getIntHeader(RESPONSE_STATUS_HEADER);
        response.setStatus(requestedStatus > -1 ? requestedStatus : defaultStatus.value());

        response.setHeader(HttpHeaders.LOCATION, location);
    }
}
```

and like this in reactive applications:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SpringAddonsOauth2ServerRedirectStrategy implements ServerRedirectStrategy {
    public static final String RESPONSE_STATUS_HEADER = "X-RESPONSE-STATUS";

    private final HttpStatus defaultStatus;

    @Override
    public Mono<Void> sendRedirect(ServerWebExchange exchange, URI location) {
        return Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
            ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
            final var status = Optional
                .ofNullable(exchange.getRequest().getHeaders().get(RESPONSE_STATUS_HEADER))
                .map(List::stream)
                .orElse(Stream.empty())
                .filter(StringUtils::hasLength)
                .findAny()
                .map(statusStr -> {
                    try {
                        final var statusCode = Integer.parseInt(statusStr);
                        return HttpStatus.valueOf(statusCode);
                    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                        return HttpStatus.valueOf(statusStr.toUpperCase());
                    }
                })
                .orElse(defaultStatus);
            response.setStatusCode(status);

            response.getHeaders().setLocation(location);
        });
    }
}
```

With a status in the `2xx` range, the redirection is not handled by the browser, so the frontends can observe the response and follow to the `Location` by changing the origin (setting the `window.location` like you're doing already, but following an URL provided by the backend, with state, nonce, etc. already set).